# Is it okay to offer remote access, or do we want everything kept in the site?

Tags: discussion

<sup>(This question did have more details, and they are just commented out, but I wanted it to be anonymous).</sup>

Is okay to use remote access to help someone if they asked here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me put it in the few words I can: **We are not a help desk service.**

Comment: But if people want to offer it?

Comment: @Tim we are still not a helpdesk service. We aren't supposed to remotely access anyones PC. Is your call to do it or not, but don't involve the site in it.

Comment: @Tim they should be considered malicious attempts, the level of trust on a connection like that I would put at "not even my brother".

Comment: Yeah - I was quite concerned by the way it was suggested, and that he might accept it.

Answer (score 2):

## You can do whatever you want!

<sub>just do not make it 'part of' Ask Ubuntu, don't advertise it here, don't suggest it, just keep that sort of stuff in chat and don't complain if something goes wrong. This also holds for sharing email addresses, real names, phone numbers, etc.</sub>